# How do you align text vertically at a proportion in a flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

For example I have the following html and css. Container has a height of 88px, and each div in container contains a span and should have half the height of container. I wish to align the spans at a proportion, like at 1/3 height in their divs. Also, the divs might contain things other than a span which might occupy full 44px height, and in that case I wouldn't want it to clip out of it's div. How do I achieve this?

```css
.container{
  height: 88px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
 
.line{
  flex: 1;
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="line">
    <span>This is line 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <span>This is line 2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I fully understood the question, but you can can use the `flex: 1 0 33%;` on the element, this way it will occupy 33% of the parent div, but will grow if it has space.
And for the vertical-alignment you can use another flex with `align-items: center`;

You can read more about flex [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex), and about flex sizing and positioning [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 88px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.line {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 0 33%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="line">
    This is line 1
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    This is line 2
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    This is line 2
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="line">
    This is line 1
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    This is line 2
  </div>
</div>
```